# R: suppressMessages from Rprintf in C++

Tags: c++, r, printf, suppress

I am writing an R-package with some C++ code running lengthy calculations. Inside the C++ code, I am using Rprintf() to output information. I tried suppressing the output from R with suppressMessages(), but this doesn't work, the messages still appear inside the R session.

I found some similar questions, where people were using printf instead of Rprintf, but I am already using Rprintf. I also tried R_ShowMessage(), which is also immediately displayed and not suppressed by suppressMessages().

Here is some example C++ code:

```
#include <R.h>
extern "C" {
void R_testprint()
{
    Rprintf("Try to suppress me!\n");
    R_ShowMessage("Try to suppress me, too!");
}
}
```

And the function that calls this code:

```
test.print <- function(string) {
    res <- .C("R_testprint")
}
```

Now, the following R code will not suppress the output:

```
> suppressMessages( test.print() )
Try to suppress me!
Try to suppress me, too!
```

I am using R version 3.1.0

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you should us the C++ code?

Answer (score 1):

Use `capture.output` in place of `suppressMessages`:

```
 b <- capture.output( test.print() )
```

Then the output is stored in character vector `b` instead of being printed.

Comment: I want to use suppressMessages, because that is what any user of this code would do. The code is part of an R-package and thus any user would use suppressMessages to suppress output.

Comment: What if the output needs to be a data.frame not a character vector?